# Javascript Array, return key:value pairs with specific key

Tags: javascript, arrays

***Problem***
I have a Javascript array and I'm trying to return only the key:value pairs that match a specific key in the most efficient way possible.

I've tried using a Foreach loop and pushing each key:value to a new array but that seems like an inefficient way to do it and overly complex.

***Code***

```
initialArray = [ { friends: [],
    otherFriends: [],
    _id: 5c6c7132f9bf4bdab9c906ff,
    user: 5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7d,
    password: '$2b$10$LMFB6CBdwxSAfjog/Uo3t.u/G0GBtzfJnYdpvlrSNchA9.jlNOdAa',
    email: 'sparky2df3dfdfdf2@gmail.com',
    createdAt: 2019-02-19T21:12:18.569Z,
    updatedAt: null,
    online: false,
    __v: 0 },
  { friends: [],
    otherFriends: [],
    _id: 5c6ccd6d3a0dc4e4951c2bee,
    user: 5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7e,
    password: '$2b$10$gEAbOAdKyHJfAksr5txUNOudCautRs1w/pubplQKzZ5PefhfOOEhq',
    email: 'fdagssd@gmail.com',
    createdAt: 2019-02-20T03:45:49.703Z,
    updatedAt: null,
    online: false,
    __v: 0 } ]
```

***Desired Array***

```
[ 
    { user: 5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7d },
    { user: 5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7e }
]
```

***Current Method***

```
const newArray = []
initialArray.forEach(element => {
            newArray.push({key: element.user});
        });
```

If anyone has any suggestions that would be amazing! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you querying the mongoose model yourself or is it an api response? :)

Comment: I’m querying mongoose myself

Comment: Then you can use a projection and only query for the user property. `MyModel.find({}, 'user');`

Comment: If you also want to strip _id do `MyModel.find({}, {'user': 1, '_id': 0});`'

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for `user` and map this [short hand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
var initialArray = [{ friends: [], otherFriends: [], _id: '5c6c7132f9bf4bdab9c906ff', user: '5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7d', password: '$2b$10$LMFB6CBdwxSAfjog/Uo3t.u/G0GBtzfJnYdpvlrSNchA9.jlNOdAa', email: 'sparky2df3dfdfdf2@gmail.com', createdAt: '2019-02-19T21:12:18.569Z', updatedAt: null, online: false, __v: 0 }, { friends: [], otherFriends: [], _id: '5c6ccd6d3a0dc4e4951c2bee', user: '5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7e', password: '$2b$10$gEAbOAdKyHJfAksr5txUNOudCautRs1w/pubplQKzZ5PefhfOOEhq', email: 'fdagssd@gmail.com', createdAt: '2019-02-20T03:45:49.703Z', updatedAt: null, online: false, __v: 0 }] 
    newArray = initialArray.map(({ user }) => ({ user }));

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: This one will be faster because destructuring and spread is faster than object.assign with a new object

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the desired keys in an array as follow.

*This example extracts two key-values*.

```js
var initialArray = [{ friends: [], otherFriends: [], _id: '5c6c7132f9bf4bdab9c906ff', user: '5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7d', password: '$2b$10$LMFB6CBdwxSAfjog/Uo3t.u/G0GBtzfJnYdpvlrSNchA9.jlNOdAa', email: 'sparky2df3dfdfdf2@gmail.com', createdAt: '2019-02-19T21:12:18.569Z', updatedAt: null, online: false, __v: 0 }, { friends: [], otherFriends: [], _id: '5c6ccd6d3a0dc4e4951c2bee', user: '5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7e', password: '$2b$10$gEAbOAdKyHJfAksr5txUNOudCautRs1w/pubplQKzZ5PefhfOOEhq', email: 'fdagssd@gmail.com', createdAt: '2019-02-20T03:45:49.703Z', updatedAt: null, online: false, __v: 0 }],
    keys = ["user", "email"], // for the desired output in the question remove "email"
    newArray = initialArray.map(o => keys.reduce((a, k) => Object.assign({}, a, {[k]: o[k]}), {}));

console.log(newArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```